# Can't find the eigenvectors of a simple 2x2 matrix

Tags: matrix, bugs, linear-algebra

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

Why can't Mathematica find the eigenvectors of this matrix?

```
Eigenvectors[{{Cos[0. + x], Exp[I x]}, {1, 0}}]

Eigenvectors::eivec0: Unable to find all eigenvectors. >>
{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

If I get rid of the (0. +) in the cosine, it works fine.

Comment: What version of MMA are you currently using?

Comment: Version 10.0.2.0, running on Mac OS X x86

Comment: V10.1 has this problem, too. Running on OS X 10.10.2. `Eigenvectors[{{Cos[0. + x], Exp[I x]}, {1, 0}} // Simplify]` works

Comment: Yeah, the Simplify inside the Eigenvectors just gets rid of the (0. +) in the Cos, which as I mentioned in the OP fixes the problem.  But obviously not always practical to Simplify if the expression's hugely complicated.  Looks like a Mathematica bug, I'll report it.

Comment: Try a  `ZeroTest -> PossibleZeroQ` for a workaround.

Comment: `Eigenvectors[
 SetPrecision[{{Cos[0. + x], Exp[I x]}, {1, 0}}, Infinity]]`

Comment: same issue in v9.

Comment: Same issue in version 8.

Comment: "10.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 9, 2015)"
This bug is still present on my version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is what Wolfram tech support told me when I filed a bug report:]

That is because using machine precision (inexact) numbers such 0. (as opposed to exact numbers like 0) forces Eigenvectors[] to seach for eigenvectors numerically and hence the error message. 
For example, please evaluate and compare the results of the following expression used with machine precision and exact numbers:

```
Eigenvectors[{{Cos[1. x], Exp[I x]}, {1, 0}}]

Eigenvectors[{{Cos[1 x], Exp[I x]}, {1, 0}}]
```

Comment: No comment on this answer. I have filed a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been fixed as of *Mathematica* 10.3.

```
$Version

(* "10.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)" *)

Eigenvectors[{{Cos[0. + x], Exp[I x]}, {1, 0}}]

(* {{-0.5 (-Cos[0. + x] + Sqrt[4 E^(I x) + Cos[0. + x]^2]), 1.}, 
    {-0.5 (-Cos[0. + x] - Sqrt[4 E^(I x) + Cos[0. + x]^2]), 1.}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Simplify@Eigenvectors[{{Cos[0. + x], Exp[I x]}, {1, 0}}]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{-1. i x} \left(-0.25 \sqrt{1.+2. e^{2 i x}+16. e^{3 i x}+e^{4 i
   x}}+0.25 e^{2. i x}+0.25\right) & 1. \\
 0.25 e^{-1. i x} \left(\sqrt{1.+2. e^{2 i x}+16. e^{3 i x}+e^{4 i
   x}}+e^{2. i x}+1.\right) & 1.
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: David, I get the same result as the OP with your expression. The `Simplify` does nothing at all for me, as `Eigenvectors` returns an error. I am on MMA v. 10.2; what version are you on? I wonder if this is some recently introduce bug with the numerical methods to calculate eigenvectors.

Comment: I'm on my home machine, v. 7.0.  $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{4} e^{-i x} \left(-\sqrt{1+2 e^{2 i x}+16 e^{3 i x}+e^{4 i
   x}}+e^{2 i x}+1\right) & 1 \\
 \frac{1}{4} e^{-i x} \left(\sqrt{1+2 e^{2 i x}+16 e^{3 i x}+e^{4 i
   x}}+e^{2 i x}+1\right) & 1
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: I'm surprised that you get the exact $1/4$ values in the result if you used a finite-precision `0.` in the argument of `Cos`.